# Apply Module Code to Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, triggers

I have created a worksheet that calls multiple modules to make different actions such as calculations or hide rows etc.

I created that workbook and codes to work with only 1 sheet, but now I copied that sheet and created 10 more, what I’m trying to do is using the same modules I created and applying that code to the new sheets.

I’m very basic in excel VBA and the topics I have found either I don’t understand them or don’t meet my needs.

Example of my code:

I put this code in Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
    ModuloAct
End If
If Target.Address = "$E$10" Then
    Colaborador
End If
If Target.Address = "$E$11" Then
    Dias
End If
End Sub
```

Example of module

```
Sub ModuloAct()

If Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(2, 5).Value = "T" Then
Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(8, 5).Value = 0.16
Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(2, 5).Value = "Tension"

End Sub
```

I know the problem is that my module is referenced to a single sheet, but I haven’t found a way to make that module apply to the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to abandon the individual [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macros in favor of a single [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro.

**[In ThisWorkbook code sheet:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx)**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    'check for a valid worksheet name
    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case "Hoja1", "Hoja2", "Hoja3", "Hoja4"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Select Case Target.Address
                Case "$E$2"
                    ModuloAct Sh
                Case "$E$10"
                    Colaborador Sh
                Case "$E$11"
                    Dias Sh
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**In Module1 code sheet:**

```
Sub ModuloAct(ws As Worksheet)

    With ws
        If .Cells(2, 5).Value = "T" Then
            .Cells(8, 5).Value = 0.16
            .Cells(2, 5).Value = "Tension"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

The Workbook_SheetChange catches changes made to any worksheet. First check to see if the worksheet is one of the ones that you want to be processed. If it is, check the Target address to see what sub procedure should be run. Pass the worksheet along to the appropriate sub procedure as a [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506.aspx) and use that parameter in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to assign the parent worksheet for all further processing.

You should remove all of the similar code in the individual worksheet code sheets' Worksheet_Change subs.